# After delete insert value in SQL Server 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

sp:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Usp_MenuMgrAddUpdMenupermission] 
@MenuID       INT,
@PermissionID INT,
@PortalID     INT,
@Username nvarchar(256)
AS
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(DELETE [dbo].[PagePermission]
                    WHERE [PortalID] = @PortalID AND
                          [MenuID] = @MenuID)

     INSERT INTO [dbo].[MenuPermission]
                    (MenuID,
                     PermissionID,
                     AddedOn,
                     Username)

        VALUES     (@MenuID,
                    @PermissionID,
                    Getdate(),
                    @UserName)
  END
```

But i got syntax  error. Please suggest the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it (**Edited for new requirements**):

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [dbo].[PagePermission]
           WHERE [PortalID] = @PortalID AND [MenuID] = @MenuID)
 BEGIN

   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   DELETE [dbo].[PagePermission]
   WHERE [PortalID] = @PortalID AND [MenuID] = @MenuID

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[MenuPermission]
           (MenuID, PermissionID, AddedOn, Username)
    VALUES (@MenuID, @PermissionID, Getdate(), @UserName)

   COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[MenuPermission]
           (MenuID, PermissionID, AddedOn, Username)
    VALUES (@MenuID, @PermissionID, Getdate(), @UserName)
END
```

Comment: @Hagon if not Exists at the same time delete query is also fire?

Comment: @ShreeKhanal Nope, the delete is in the if statement and after the start of the transaction.

Comment: its not work.Its only delete n update existing menu id which i pass.I want if new menu id is supplied then instead of delete query  insert query fire.Any way Thanks.

Comment: your welcome thanks anyway you not have in original question later

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in one statement using the [OUTPUT Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) :

```
DELETE [dbo].[PagePermission]
    OUTPUT @MenuID,@PermissionID,Getdate(),@UserName
        INTO [dbo].[MenuPermission]
    WHERE [PortalID] = @PortalID AND [MenuID] = @MenuID
```

working example:

```
DECLARE @PagePermission TABLE (PortalID int, MenuID int)
INSERT INTO @PagePermission VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO @PagePermission VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO @PagePermission VALUES (3,2)
INSERT INTO @PagePermission VALUES (4,2)

DECLARE @MenuPermission TABLE (MenuID int, PermissionID int,YourDate datetime, UserName varchar(10))

DECLARE @MenuID        int
       ,@PermissionID  int
       ,@UserName      varchar(10)
      ,@PortalID       int

SELECT @MenuID        =1
      ,@PermissionID  =100
      ,@UserName      ='xyz'
      ,@PortalID      =2

DELETE @PagePermission
    OUTPUT @MenuID,@PermissionID,Getdate(),@UserName
        INTO @MenuPermission
    WHERE PortalID = @PortalID AND MenuID = @MenuID

select * from @PagePermission

select * from @MenuPermission
```

OUTPUT:

```
PortalID    MenuID
----------- -----------
1           1
3           2
4           2

(3 row(s) affected)

MenuID      PermissionID YourDate                UserName
----------- ------------ ----------------------- ----------
1           100          2011-11-09 09:18:52.693 xyz

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) variable:

```
DELETE [dbo].[PagePermission] WHERE [PortalID] = @PortalID AND [MenuID] = @MenuID

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MenuPermission] ...
```

Comment: i don't understand.plz explain.I should not want delete query is fire when condition is not match.

Comment: What this code does is: 1. delete rows 2. if any row was deleted, then do the insert. If you want something else, please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: Delete row if exist.If not why should delete query is fired ? only insert query execute. I m confuse.

Comment: @ShreeKhanal: You'd have to first check whether there are rows to delete (search for them), then, if there were any such rows, issue the DELETE statement, which in turn would have to first search for the rows to be deleted, as specified in its `WHERE` clause, then perform the actual delete. So why search twice? Just go with the DELETE, as Xavier is suggesting here, and if the DELETE actually deletes any rows, the `@@ROWCOUNT` global variable will be set to a non-zero value. Based on that you will issue the INSERT. That way it's less expensive, unless I'm missing something in your requirements.

Comment: @ShreeKhanal: … (which you haven't stated properly *in your question*, by the way).